# Is 9 the only composite index of a Pell semiprime?

Tags: number-theory

Let $P(n)$ indicate the nth [Pell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number), and consider $S:=\{n \mid P(n) \text{ is a semiprime}\}$.

Since $n\mid m \Rightarrow P(n)\mid P(m)$, members of S have at most two distinct prime factors. It isn't hard to see that only prime powers are in S: for $p>q>1$, $\frac{P(pq)}{P(p)P(q)} \approx 2\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{pq-p-q} $.

$P(9)=985=5*197=P(3)*197$ so $9\in S$. A moment with Mathematica shows this is the only composite member of S below 20,000. (Note that $P(20000)$ is a 7656-digit number.)

Any ideas as to how one might show it's the only composite in S?